# Calling map function (Indirection requires pointer operand)

Tags: c++

I was trying to call a function from a map.

The variable looks like this:

```
std::map<std::string, void (AbstractVM::*)(IOperand *)> _func;
```

I initialize it like this:

```
_func = {
    {"push", &AbstractVM::push},
    {"pop", &AbstractVM::pop},
    {"clear", &AbstractVM::clear},
    {"dup", &AbstractVM::dup}
}
```

The struct that I use for the loop:

```
typedef struct instruction_s {
    std::string instruction;
    std::string operand;
    std::string number;
    IOperand *value;
} instruction_t;
```

How I implement the code, inside a function of the AbstractVM class:

```
for (const auto& instruction : _instructions) {
    for (const auto& func : _func) {
        if (func.first == instruction.instruction) {
            (*func.second)(instruction.value);
            break;
        }
    }
}
```

And I have this error:

> Indirection requires pointer operand ('void (AbstractVM::*)(IOperand *)' invalid)

Any suggestions?

Comment: You have a pointer to member function. To call it, you also need an object itself (an instance of AbstractVM).

Comment: So, which `AbstractVM` object you want to "push" (pop/clear/duplicate)?

Comment: The syntax for calling a pointer-to-member-function would be `(some_abstract_vm.*func.second)(instruction.value);` or `(pointer_to_some_abstract_vm->*func.second)(instruction.value);`

Comment: @MilesBudnek I don't understand quite well with some_abstract_vm or pointer_to_some_abstract_vm. I forgot to say that is inside an AbstractVM function

Comment: @JonathanGómez Then the pointer you need is `this`. You should look up "how to use a pointer-to-member-function" and provide a complete [mcve] next time.

Comment: @KamilCuk I don't understand the question

Comment: @AsteroidsWithWings, it works, but what's wrong with my question. Should I do all in one function, in the question?

Comment: Inside one of `AbstractVM`'s member functions, `this` is a pointer to an `AbstractVM`, so you want `(this->*func.second)(instruction.value)`.

Comment: As you said yourself, a crucial detail is missing. Click on the link I gave you to find out about [mcve]s.